# How to check stateChanged in a dynamic checkbox list in PyQt4

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt4

So I'm adding checkboxes from a list in PyQt4. But I can't figure a way to use stateChanged for each one of them in my Window class.

This is the function to add them from the list elements:

```py
  def addCheckbox(self):
        colunas = Graphic(self.caminho).getColunas()
        for col in colunas:
            c = QtGui.QCheckBox(col, self, objectName=col)
            self.layout.addWidget(c)
```

I've tried to get their object names in a `while True` and use with:

```
self.name.stateChanged.connect(self.clickBox)
```

But that just freezes the code.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
def clickBoxStateChanged(self, objectName):
    def stateChanged(state):
        print(objectName)
        print(state)
    return stateChanged
```

Then, in your loop:

```
  for col in colunas:
        c = QtGui.QCheckBox(col, self, objectName=col)
        c.stateChanged.connect(self.clickBoxStateChanged(col))
        self.layout.addWidget(c)
```